# create field.val array from class selector

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to jquery and just looking for some help.

current code:

```
var formData = {
                    'settings'          : $('input[name=settings]').val(),       
                    'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                    'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
                    'superheroAlias'    : $('input[name=superheroAlias]').val()
                };
```

What im looking to do is instead of declare each individual field is maybe add a class to each input and pick up each field that way.

Im guessing this is possible but I've tried so many diffent ways and i feel im just confusing myself more

Comment: Are you using this in an AJAX call? You could use `$("#formID").serialize()` to get all the fields in the form.

Comment: If the answer is not clear/working or you meant something else, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use a *custom class* and [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
var formData = {};

$('.my-class').each(function(){
  formData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  });

console.log(formData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="my-class" name="settings" value="1"/>
<input class="my-class" name="name" value="2"/>
<input class="my-class" name="email" value="3"/>
<input class="my-class" name="superheroAlias" value="4"/>
```